# Store currency exchange rates in SQL Server and displaying them

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to allow user use my page to do currency exchange rate for a few currencies (2-3 of them) and display them based on the rates stored in SQL Server. I want to display 3 different rates for each single currency when the user clicks the button to convert so I can let user compare which has the best rate.

What will it be a better to do it? Will be using c#, asp.net and SQL Server.

This is my sql table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE CurrencyExchange (
currency CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
rate MONEY NOT NULL,
source VARCHAR NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (currency, rate))
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it? 
Well you never really gave us the requirements of your program. That's a hard question to answer when you give us 2-3 sentences worth.

You might try and cache your sql data somewhere (another hidden page, .csv document, or other) and then retrieve those values from the cache on page-load. That way you aren't bogging down your sql server. Just be sure to make a stored procedure on sql to update the cache as often as you find necessary.

That's probably the simplest way I can imagine you doing this. It also prevents you from having to directly connect to sql from your website, which you might want for security reasons.

But as I said, it's hard to suggest methods when we know so little information. What have you tried so far? What are you trying to avoid? What are you trying to achieve? Ask yourself those questions, then go from there.

You might start looking here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Comment: How can i cache my sql data on page load?

Comment: 1. Create stored procedure on SQL which writes your sql table info to a .csv file or such (http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/SQL_Syntax/Q_28458147.html) 2. Open the file on page load and parse the data, saving the data as a session variable or such. OR just do it the way you thought it out. Make a sql connection, query your database, parse the datatable you retrieve, and do whatever it is you want with it.

Comment: Either route you take will take considerable time if you haven't done anything with c# and sql before. But there are tons of guides of the sort you can find out there. But if you want the quick and dirty, you could use something like parse.com to hold your sql data and forget all that query nonsense :) Then just make some calls to the api and you should be good to go :)